# Samples drawn(iid) from univariate gaussian. Does their combination is drawn from multivariate gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, iid

If $x_i \sim \mathrm{N}(0,1)$ for i = 1:n and $x_i$ are iid, is it true that $(x_1, x_2, ...,x_{n}) \sim \mathrm{N}(0,I)$ where I is identity matrix of size n?

If $x_i \sim \mathrm{N}(0,\sigma)$ for i = 1:n and $x_i$ are iid, is it true that $(x_1, x_2, ...,x_{n}) \sim \mathrm{N}(0,\sigma I)$ where I is identity matrix of size n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can show this through many ways. I think the easiest way would be to check if the product of their moment generating functions is equal to the multivariate normal moment generating function.